# Excel VBA - MySQL (tidb) ODBC - Lost connection to MySQL server during query Error, but weirdly only for a certain type of query

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

I currently have an Excel VBA Code that creates an ODBC Connection to a MySQL (tidb) Server, which works fine for almost all queries, except one (or two, they're the same).

```
Sub CONNECT()

    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Port As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    
    Server_Name = "localhost"
    Port = "4000"
    User_ID = "test"
    Password = "passw0rd"

    If (CN Is Nothing) Then
        Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
    End If
    
    If Not (CN.State = 1) Then
        CN.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}" & _
            ";Server=" & Server_Name & ":" & Port & _
            ";Uid=" & User_ID & _
            ";Pwd=" & Password & _
            ";OPTION=3;AUTO_RECONNECT=1;Packet Size=1073741823" & _
            ";ConnectTimeout=300;InteractiveTimeout=300;CommandTimeout=300;"
    End If

End Sub

Sub DISCONNECT()
    
    If Not (CN Is Nothing) Then
        If Not (CN.State = 0) Then
            CN.Close
            Set CN = Nothing
        End If
    Else
    End If

End Sub

Sub QRY(dest As Range, script As String)

    On Error GoTo errHandling

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

    cmd.ActiveConnection = CN
    cmd.CommandText = script
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 300

    Set rs = cmd.execute

    dest.CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    Exit Sub

errHandling:
    If InStr(Err.Description, "Lost connection") <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print (Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss") & " " & dest.Address & " Lost Connection Error")
    End If

End Sub

Sub EXECUTE()

Dim script1 As String
Dim script2 As String
Dim script3 As String
Dim script4 As String
Dim script5 As String
Dim script6 As String

For i = 1 to 100

    CONNECT

    SS = Range("C" & i).Value
    SV = Range("D" & i).Value
    TS = Range("E" & i).Value
    TT = Range("F" & i).Value

    script1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" & SS & "' AND TABLE_NAME = '" & SV & "'"
    script2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" & TS & "' AND TABLE_NAME = '" & TT & "'"
    script3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & SS & "." & SV & ""
    script4 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & TS & "." & TT & ""
    script5 = "WITH V AS (SELECT lower(column_name) as col FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = '" & SS & "' AND table_name = '" & SV & "'), T AS (SELECT lower(column_name) as col FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = '" & TS & "' AND table_name = '" & TT & "') SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V LEFT JOIN T ON v.col = t.col WHERE t.col IS NULL"
    script6 = "WITH V AS (SELECT lower(column_name) as col FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = '" & SS & "' AND table_name = '" & SV & "'), T AS (SELECT lower(column_name) as col FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = '" & TS & "' AND table_name = '" & TT & "') SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T LEFT JOIN V ON t.col = v.col WHERE v.col IS NULL"

    QRY Range("H" & i), script1
    QRY Range("I" & i), script2
    QRY Range("J" & i), script3
    QRY Range("K" & i), script4
    QRY Range("L" & i), script5
    QRY Range("M" & i), script6

    DISCONNECT

Next i

End Sub
```

So have subs CONNECT, DISCONNECT and QRY that I use in this final sub of mine, EXECUTE.

In the Sub EXECUTE which we use to run the Macro, there is this For Loop where for each loop I am trying to execute 6 different scripts (script1-6). Scripts 1 to 4 run without no issues whatsoever. However, Scripts 5 and 6 have a strange behaviour, where *sometimes* it would return the error: **[mysqld-5.7.25-TiDB-v5.1.5] Lost connection to MySQL server during query**.

When I say *sometimes*, I mean that out of a 100 times, the error would occur around 20-30 times.

I've tried multiple different queries that still gives me the same result but the behaviour didn't go away, I'm assuming because information_schema.columns is still involved.

I've also tried a few other stuffs like adding timeout and packet size to the connection string, added timeout to the adodb objects, and even updated the variables on the server side like wait_timeout, net_read_timeout, etc. all to 600 seconds, but nothing better. I'm starting to think it might be because it's not purely mysql but actually tidb.

A small example of the result after I run EXECUTE:
[image]

I'm running out of options here and if anyone can give me anything I can work with I'd really appreciate it.

I also apologize if the post is not correct in anyway, please let me know, will fix it.

Comment: I have used CTEs before without issues, and I'm just wondering that if it's about support then shouldn't it happen every time? why does it only not work sometimes? I also tried a similar query to this that's not CTE but just sub-query directly, and same result.

Comment: Note that this is TiDB, which is a MySQL compatible database that supports CTE's. The docs for this can be found here: https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/sql-statement-with

Comment: Maybe you are facing a connection timeout. While your command timeouts is 300, your connection timeout is also 300. So potentially long running queries causes connection loss. Try setting [connection timeout to zero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/connectiontimeout-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver16) or `300 * 6`.

Comment: Oh wait...actually I see you are also running in a `For` loop, opening/closing the connection 100 times! Try opening connection once with no timeout limit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using TiDB v5.1.5. Could you check if this also happens with TiDB v7.0.0 (the latest development milestone release) or with v6.5.2 (the latest long term support release)? While this should work with v5.1 there have been a few changes in later releases that might fix this.

The "Lost connection to MySQL server during query." message means that the network connection stopped working. Either because of the server closing the network connection of because of some network issue. Could you look in the logs of TiDB to see if there is any message indicating about why this might happen? How long do the queries take to execute?

Disclosure: I'm working for PingCAP, the company making TiDB.

Comment: I can't dabble around with the different versions, as the 5.1.5 is what the place i'm working for is currently using, and I only have DBA access (SELECT, CREATE, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) for it. For logs, could you help me out and let me know more specifically where I can find it, so may be I can follow up with the infra team here to get them. For execution time, the queries 5 and 6 takes between 1.5 to 2 seconds to execute, while the first 4 takes between 0.8 and 1.2 seconds.

Comment: Trying different versions might be possible with [TiUP Playground](https://tiup.io) or with a TiDB Cloud account (free tier).

Comment: There is some more info on https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/error-codes#mysql-native-error-messages I'm sure your infra team knows where to find them. This depends on if this is deployed on cloud, with kubernetes or with tiup cluster.

Comment: With `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'hostname'` you could check if you always get connected to the same host and if that host has been recently restarted or not. If the uptime is low this might indicate that the host you are connected to has been restarted recently which would cause network connections to die.